# Correct caret position after replacing a selection of text in a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, caret

I want the below method to replace a selection of text in a `JTextField` and replace it with some input `String`. My problem is that if I select more than a single character in the `JTextField`, the caret position skips ahead.

How can I ensure that the caret position stays in the correct position?

```
private void addStringAtCaretPos(String c) {
        final int caretPosition = inputTextField.getCaretPosition();
        inputTextField.replaceSelection(c);

        inputTextField.requestFocus();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                inputTextField.setCaretPosition(caretPosition + 1);
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I select more than a single character in the JTextField, the caret position skips ahead.

```
final int caretPosition = inputTextField.getCaretPosition();
```

Typically when you select text you select from left to right so the caret position is at the end of the text you want to replace.

I would think you should be using:

```
final int caretPosition = inputTextField.getSelectionStart();
```